# Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'option'

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to implement `select` in Angular 5 but I am constantly getting this

[image]

I've tried many StackOverflow questions already, The only difference is - My components are inside another module within the application which is at the end injected into the main module eventually. I've also tried injecting the `FormsModule` inside the inner module. I have tried importing `ReactiveFormsModule`  but didn't work.

I've added `FormsModule` to imports like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...CombineComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
});
```

and here is my component markup

```
<label for="ctn" class="d-inline-block pl-1 semi-bold">Current active number</label>
  <select
    #selectElem
    class="custom-select"
    id="ctn"
    (change)="onCTNChange(selectElem.value)"
    formControlName="state"
  >
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
    <option *ngFor="let ctn of availableCTN" [ngValue]="ctn.value">
      {{ctn.text}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `value`:

```
[value]="ctn.value"
```

Comment: It's working, but I still not able to bind the value. It's not setting it to the default value.

Comment: because adding `[ngModel]` also throw a similar error

Comment: What error does ngModel throw? Are you importing FormsModule? .... import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

Comment: Yes, I am importing it. `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'`

Comment: Ok it worked. I was using CommonsModule and I had to import FormsModule inside the child module aswell

Answer (score 2):

I was doing a very silly mistake and got into this issue.

1. Instead of using `[ngValue]="ctn.value"`
2. I was supposed to use `[value]` I was importing `formsModule` inside parent module, I should have imported it in child module to make `[(ngModel)]` work
3. `[value]` should be `[(value)]` if we want the default selection show up.

so my final component code is.

```
<label for="ctn" class="d-inline-block pl-1 semi-bold">Current active number</label>
  <select
    #selectCTN
    class="custom-select"
    id="ctn"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCTN"
    (change)="onCTNChange(selectCTN.value)"
  >
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
    <option *ngFor="let ctn of availableCTN" [(value)]="ctn.value">
      {{ctn.text}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[value] will work in this case. In my case also, I haven't used formmodule, just using it inside a  tag, working fine.