# Angular 5 Set default value on template driven form input

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular5, angular-forms

I'm having trouble setting the value of a template driven form input. The value is coming from an `editMovie` object. I want the form to be filled with the editMovie values when shown and the user can then edit a part of the editMovie object or leave it the same. The form value is being set correctly for inputs that don't have `[(ngModel)]` attachted to them but the one's that do won't set a default value. Here is an example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imdb">Edit IMDb ID</label>
    <input #editImdb type="text" class="form-control" name="imdb" [(ngModel)]="editReviewForm.imdb" [value]="editMovie.imdb" required="" />
    <div class="mt-1" style="color:red">
        *required
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="trailer">Edit Youtube Trailer</label>
    <input #editTrailer type="text" class="form-control" name="trailer" value="{{ editMovie.trailer }}" />
</div>
```

The first one doesn't work while the second one does. Following SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444765/cant-bind-to-ngvalue-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-option) I tried putting the value property in a two way data binding like this: `[(value)]` but that didn't work. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936769/angular-5-templated-form-selected-dropdown-value-doesnt-show) SO question I tried `[ngValue]` but this threw a parse error in the browser `Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

Does anybody know how to bind the value for a template driven form input?

Comment: You can set FormControl name to html, define it in .ts file and use patchValue or setValue..

Comment: That's for reactive forms. The OP said template driven forms.

Comment: When using template-driven forms, your best bet is to use `[(ngModel)]` and NOT the `value`. `ngModel` is for two way binding, which sets the default and keeps the associated component property in sync. Binding also to the `value` property is most likely confusing things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DeborahK. How would I do that? In the docs, so far the only time I see them set a value is with options and they use `[value]`. How would I use `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: Cool beans, I was misunderstanding how to use [(ngModule)] a second look cleared things up. Thanks @DeborahK. On an unrelated note, how did you make a hyperlink that took me halfway down the page?

Comment: In the docs, if you hover over any of the section titles, you'll see a link icon to the left of the title. Click on that to get a direct link to a section in the docs.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've updated your code below. I don't see any component code, so I guessed on the appropriate bindings.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imdb">Edit IMDb ID</label>
    <input #editImdb type="text" class="form-control" 
           id="imdb" [(ngModel)]="editMovie.imdb" required />
    <div class="mt-1" style="color:red">
        *required
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="trailer">Edit Youtube Trailer</label>
    <input #editTrailer type="text" class="form-control" 
           id="trailer" [(ngModel)]="editMovie.trailer" />
</div>
```

The two-way binding defined by `[(ngModel)]` takes the value of the component's property and assigns it as the default. As the user makes any change to the value, that value is then modified in the component's property, basically keeping the input element and component property in sync.

Also, according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

... the `label for` is expecting to match an input element's `id` property, not the `name` property. I also changed that above.